# Stretch list items <li> to fill the width of <ul>

Tags: css

I have an unordered list (`<ul>`) with various number of items (`<li>`) in it. I want to use one CSS styling that allows the items to stretch to the width of the list.

This is what I have:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

HTML:

```
These 4 items should fill the width:<br/>
<ul id="ul1">
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
</ul>
<br/>
These 5 items should fill the width:<br/>
<ul id="ul2">
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
</ul>
<br/>
And so on and so forth...
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AwWUA/) to get you started.

Note: I don't want to [hard-code the `width` in CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/AwWUA/1/).
Note: If you are wondering about the use-case, this is a navigation structure in a responsive design and I want the list items to always fill up the available width no matter what is the resolution.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AwWUA/9/)***
HI now you can do this

**Used to** `display :table` and `display:table-cell`

as like this

**Css**

```
ul {
    border:1px dotted black;
    padding: 0;
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
li {
    background-color: red;
    display:table-cell;
}
li:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: #0F0;
}
```

**Now define your parent** `display:table;` or `width:100%;` and **define your child** `display:table-cell;`

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AwWUA/9/)***

Comment: Good one, what about cross browser compatibility?

Comment: But if your list Items have different lengthed words then this looks really ugly

Answer (score 15):

Easy solution with

```
ul {
    display: flex;
}

ul li {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you add some explenation to your answer? Only showing code can be confusing.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way:

```css
ul {
    display: flex;
}

ul li {
    /*this instruction means "To split space between all 'li' elements evenly*/
    flex: 1;
}
```

More detailed about `flex` property you can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/flex).

Comment: Still working to this day, simple and fast

Answer (score 1):

I've got the simplest solution. 
`<ul style="padding: 0;">
   <li style="list-style-type: none;margin:0;"></li>
</ul>`

Answer (score 0):

```
#ul1 {
display: block;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}

li-Class{
width: 100%
}
```

Note: display can be inline-block with width:100% and this code is for those who are looking to arrange li block wise.