# Stretch <li> background to fill width of <ul>

Tags: html, css, background-color, styling

Hey guys I cannot figure out how to stretch an li background to fill out the width of its parent ul. Thus the aqua rectangle in the even messages do not cover the entire area. I need the aqua rectangles to be the same size as the light blue rectangles.

This is a picture of my application, notice the missing piecing denoted by the red oval, they are not the correct color:
[image]

This is the relevant portion of the EJS (treat it as html) code:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
}

#nav-bar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#messages {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#messages li {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

#messages li:nth-child(even) {
  background: #88e9e1;
}

#online-users {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

#online-users li:nth-child(odd) {
  color: #373737;
}

#online-users li:nth-child(even) {
  color: #777777;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
}

#middle-div {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #202020;
}

#chat-column {
  height: 65vh;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-right: 1px solid #202020;
  /* Keep messages from overflowing out of rectangle */
  word-wrap: break-word;
  /* Contain messages as a scrollable list inside the rectangle */
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#users-column {
  height: 65vh;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-left: 1px solid #202020;
  /* Keep usernames from overflowing out of rectangle */
  word-wrap: break-word;
  /* Contain usernames as a scrollable list inside the rectangle */
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#bottom-div {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container" id="container">
  <div class="row" id="top-div">
    <!-- The users username -->
    <h3 class="text-primary">Logged in as: <i><b><span id="username"><%= loggedInUser.username %></span></b></i></h1>
  </div>

  <div class="row" id="middle-div">
    <div class="form-group" id="chat-and-users">
      <div>
        <div class="col-xs-9 bg-info" id="chat-column">
          <!-- Chat Column -->
          <ul id="messages">
            <li>Test Text</li>
     <li>Test Text</li>
     <li>Test Text</li>
     <li>Test Text</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 bg-success" id="users-column">
          <!-- Users Column -->
          <h4><b>Online Users:</b></h4>
          <ul id="online-users">
            <li>Test Text</li>
     <li>Test Text</li>
     <li>Test Text</li>
     <li>Test Text</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="bottom-div">
    <form action="" id="input-button-form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="message-input" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" placeholder="Type a message...">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" id="button-send" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```

Notes:

1. Messages come from a front end file and are appended as an li to the ul with id "messages"
2. The following link was not helpful, so please do not cite it: [Stretch list items <li> to fill the width of <ul>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397135/stretch-list-items-li-to-fill-the-width-of-ul)

Comment: Please provide working code.

Comment: All the code? It involves Server Side, Front End, Bootstrap, Express, Passport, Mongoose and more. It is so much, that I cannot possibly share it all. Hence why I only shared the relevant stuff to this issue

Comment: Ok then please provide `ul` inside generated code.

Comment: Not *all* the code is required - just a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example, preferably in an embedded Code Snippet for user-friendly reproduction and troubleshooting.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `#messages li { 
    padding: 5px 10px; `
    **`min-width:100%`;**
} and make sure `#messages` doesn't have any padding elsewhere

Comment: @Frankg26: all you need to provide is the complete CSS for `#chat-column`, `#users-column` and `children`. But I think I know what causes that, I tried to answer below. `LI`s are stretched, but you have padding on parents

Comment: Hey @zerOOne thanks for the reply, but it did not fix the issue!

Comment: @Frankg26 check my answer I have added it.

Comment: It would appear that the simplest solution here would be to remove the `margin` property rules declared on the containing `ul` element - this is a default user agent style that any list (ordered or unordered) will have, so reset this property value and define your spacing with `padding` on the nested list items instead. Have you considered or explored this solution? And if so, can you explain why it would not suit your application?

Comment: Provide link for this so we can check this

Comment: I added working code!! How can I provide a link?

Comment: Thank you @weBer for fixing my post!

Comment: A working code snippet is added and the issue becomes immediately clear just by inspecting the elements in question - that spacing is coming from the column `padding` on the element `#chat-column`.

Comment: @Frankg26: in updated answer still missing the CSS for parents of these `UL`s. Any of them has padding/margin,  you don't show us. Add a link to you website, or create a JSFiddle where problem is visible.

Comment: @panther I have provided all the code I wrote, what exactly do you mean by the "CSS for parents of these ULs"?

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError can you be a bit more specific on where this error occurs? I never added padding to #chat-column

Comment: @Frankg26: I see, I updated my answer, now it's clear. Remove padding from parent. Andre Ramadhan on another answer tells you the same.

Comment: Check your styles, the framework you are using (bootstrap) is attributing `padding` property values to the class `.col-xs-3`. Inspect the element in question to view the computed styles and the box-model (left-click element, click "Inspect")

Comment: Thank you to everybody that participated in this question!!! My question has been answered!!! I appreciate the help I got from everybody!!!

Comment: Your LI does fill the UL. Try looking at the DIV that contains the UL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I think this will work for you fine:***

I have added this following code:

```
#messages li {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    width: calc(100% + 30px);
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
}

#nav-bar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#messages {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#messages li {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: calc(100% + 30px);
  margin-left: -15px;
}

#messages li:nth-child(even) {
  background: #88e9e1;
}

#online-users {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

#online-users li:nth-child(odd) {
  color: #373737;
}

#online-users li:nth-child(even) {
  color: #777777;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
}

#middle-div {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #202020;
}

#chat-column {
  height: 65vh;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-right: 1px solid #202020;
  /* Keep messages from overflowing out of rectangle */
  word-wrap: break-word;
  /* Contain messages as a scrollable list inside the rectangle */
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#users-column {
  height: 65vh;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-left: 1px solid #202020;
  /* Keep usernames from overflowing out of rectangle */
  word-wrap: break-word;
  /* Contain usernames as a scrollable list inside the rectangle */
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#bottom-div {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="container">
  <div class="row" id="top-div">
    <!-- The users username -->
    <h3 class="text-primary">
    Logged in as: <i><b><span id="username"><%= loggedInUser.username %></span></b></i></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="middle-div">
    <div class="form-group" id="chat-and-users">
      <div>
        <div class="col-xs-9 bg-info" id="chat-column">
          <!-- Chat Column -->
          <ul id="messages">
            <li>Test Text</li>
            <li>Test Text</li>
            <li>Test Text</li>
            <li>Test Text</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 bg-success" id="users-column">
          <!-- Users Column -->
          <h4><b>Online Users:</b></h4>
          <ul id="online-users">
            <li>Test Text</li>
            <li>Test Text</li>
            <li>Test Text</li>
            <li>Test Text</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="bottom-div">
    <form action="" id="input-button-form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="message-input" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" placeholder="Type a message...">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" id="button-send" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this was helpfull for you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. I have added `before` and `after` css:

```
#messages li{
    position:relative;
}
#messages li:nth-child(2n):before {
    content: "";
    width: 15px;
    left: -15px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: #88e9e1;
    position: absolute;
}
#messages li:nth-child(2n):after{
    content: "";
    width: 15px;
    right: -15px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: #88e9e1;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
}

#nav-bar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#messages {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#messages li {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#messages li:nth-child(even) {
  background: #88e9e1;
}

#messages li:nth-child(2n)::before {
  content: "";
  width: 15px;
  left: -15px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #88e9e1;
  position: absolute;
}

#messages li:nth-child(2n)::after {
  content: "";
  width: 15px;
  right: -15px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #88e9e1;
  position: absolute;
}

#online-users {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

#online-users li:nth-child(odd) {
  color: #373737;
}

#online-users li:nth-child(even) {
  color: #777777;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
}

#middle-div {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #202020;
}

#chat-column {
  height: 65vh;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-right: 1px solid #202020;
  /* Keep messages from overflowing out of rectangle */
  word-wrap: break-word;
  /* Contain messages as a scrollable list inside the rectangle */
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#users-column {
  height: 65vh;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-left: 1px solid #202020;
  /* Keep usernames from overflowing out of rectangle */
  word-wrap: break-word;
  /* Contain usernames as a scrollable list inside the rectangle */
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#bottom-div {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="container">
  <div class="row" id="top-div">
    <!-- The users username -->
    <h3 class="text-primary">Logged in as: <i><b><span id="username"><%= loggedInUser.username %></span></b></i></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="middle-div">
    <div class="form-group" id="chat-and-users">
      <div>
        <div class="col-xs-9 bg-info" id="chat-column">
          <!-- Chat Column -->
          <ul id="messages">
            <!-- Messages go here -->
            <li>demo test</li>
            <li>demo test demo test</li>
            <li>demo test</li>
            <li>demo test demo test</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 bg-success" id="users-column">
          <!-- Users Column -->
          <h4><b>Online Users:</b></h4>
          <ul id="online-users">
            <!-- Online users go here -->
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="bottom-div">
    <form action="" id="input-button-form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="message-input" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" placeholder="Type a message...">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" id="button-send" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's very ugly. Wait for rest info from OP, than is possible to find a solution, not this ugly thing. It isn't the solution, just bad fix (it probably looks as OP wants, but isn't a sulotion).

Comment: @panther ok as you wish but this is proper solution as user want. Don't give downvote because my answer is correct.

Comment: Isn't correct at all. If OP wants to set background to LI, really don't want to add two other (pseudo)elements. You can think it's okay, I don't think so.

Comment: @panther ok you think that (pseudo)elements is not correct answer then provide your answer for better solution.

Comment: Waiting for relevant code. Don't know which element has margin/paddign there. Any of parent, the solution is just to remove it from there. My answer was just a tip as I wrote above, don't get downvotes and I removed it myself when OP said I had a bad tip (idea was good). I downvoted your answer not because of my previous one, but because it isn't good. No more comments for this.

Comment: @panther , no this is not solution that remove padding because bootstrap has `col` and its contain by default padding and if you remove it then `ul` also come in left side that OP don't want.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `col-xs-9` it gave you `padding-right: 15px;padding-left: 15px;` . Simplest answer is to give the `#chat-column {padding:0;}`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
}

#nav-bar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#messages {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#messages li {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

#messages li:nth-child(even) {
  background: #88e9e1;
}

#online-users {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

#online-users li:nth-child(odd) {
  color: #373737;
}

#online-users li:nth-child(even) {
  color: #777777;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
}

#middle-div {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #202020;
}

#chat-column {
padding:0;
  height: 65vh;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-right: 1px solid #202020;
  /* Keep messages from overflowing out of rectangle */
  word-wrap: break-word;
  /* Contain messages as a scrollable list inside the rectangle */
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#users-column {
  height: 65vh;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-left: 1px solid #202020;
  /* Keep usernames from overflowing out of rectangle */
  word-wrap: break-word;
  /* Contain usernames as a scrollable list inside the rectangle */
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#bottom-div {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container" id="container">
  <div class="row" id="top-div">
    <!-- The users username -->
    <h3 class="text-primary">Logged in as: <i><b><span id="username"><%= loggedInUser.username %></span></b></i></h1>
  </div>

  <div class="row" id="middle-div">
    <div class="form-group" id="chat-and-users">
      <div>
        <div class="col-xs-9 bg-info" id="chat-column">
          <!-- Chat Column -->
          <ul id="messages">
            <li>Test Text</li>
     <li>Test Text</li>
     <li>Test Text</li>
     <li>Test Text</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 bg-success" id="users-column">
          <!-- Users Column -->
          <h4><b>Online Users:</b></h4>
          <ul id="online-users">
            <li>Test Text</li>
     <li>Test Text</li>
     <li>Test Text</li>
     <li>Test Text</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="bottom-div">
    <form action="" id="input-button-form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="message-input" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" placeholder="Type a message...">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" id="button-send" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`#chat-column` has left and right padding (from `.col-xs-9` class), just remove it.

```
#chat-column {padding: 0;}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
}

#nav-bar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#chat-column {padding: 0;}

#messages {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#messages li {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

#messages li:nth-child(even) {
  background: #88e9e1;
}

#online-users {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

#online-users li:nth-child(odd) {
  color: #373737;
}

#online-users li:nth-child(even) {
  color: #777777;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
}

#middle-div {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #202020;
}

#chat-column {
  height: 65vh;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-right: 1px solid #202020;
  /* Keep messages from overflowing out of rectangle */
  word-wrap: break-word;
  /* Contain messages as a scrollable list inside the rectangle */
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#users-column {
  height: 65vh;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-left: 1px solid #202020;
  /* Keep usernames from overflowing out of rectangle */
  word-wrap: break-word;
  /* Contain usernames as a scrollable list inside the rectangle */
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#bottom-div {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container" id="container">
  <div class="row" id="top-div">
    <!-- The users username -->
    <h3 class="text-primary">Logged in as: <i><b><span id="username"><%= loggedInUser.username %></span></b></i></h1>
  </div>

  <div class="row" id="middle-div">
    <div class="form-group" id="chat-and-users">
      <div>
        <div class="col-xs-9 bg-info" id="chat-column">
          <!-- Chat Column -->
          <ul id="messages">
            <li>Test Text</li>
     <li>Test Text</li>
     <li>Test Text</li>
     <li>Test Text</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 bg-success" id="users-column">
          <!-- Users Column -->
          <h4><b>Online Users:</b></h4>
          <ul id="online-users">
            <li>Test Text</li>
     <li>Test Text</li>
     <li>Test Text</li>
     <li>Test Text</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="bottom-div">
    <form action="" id="input-button-form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="message-input" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" placeholder="Type a message...">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" id="button-send" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: If I remove that class, then it messes up the entire Bootstrap Grid, thus making an even bigger problem...

Comment: @Frankg26: not remove, just add this piece of code into your CSS. Bootstrap classes should stay there.

Comment: This is the problem, plain and simple. The problem is not in the ul. It is in the containing div. Really the OP just needs to learn how to use the devtools properly.

Comment: @panther if you could provide a sample code it could have better for an answer. With your reputation, you should know that better than me bro. :)

Comment: @weBer: If you think so.

Comment: @weBer: I was there before these code snippets was there, I don't know how to create them (I've just copy it from question). PS. It's a little bit better solution than yours counting width and adding negative margins. More easy&clean. Just for info and possible CSS grow :-)

Comment: @panther you could just edit the Q to create the snippet as I did right and if it's about the answer it's all up to to the one who asks the question to decide the convenience of the answer. We all can just suggest to him..

Answer (score 0):

Please add class `.mx-0` with the class row.

```
.mx-0{
margin-left:0 !important;
margin-right:0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi! and to which tags should I assign this class to?

Comment: <div class="row" id="middle-div">

Comment: @Frankg26: it isn't the solution, don't try it. Add relevant CSS. `#middle-div` has ho margin.